# configure eclipse 3.4 with maven 2.x or 3.0

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, maven, maven-plugin

I want to configure eclips(3.4.2) GANYMEDE with maven 2.x or 3.0,anyone tell me how I can do this??I tried to add
software updates--->Available software--->maven 
I couldn't find maven plug-in from that,Then after I tried some repositories using "add site" but that didn't success.
thanxx

Comment: I get the same error "Repository not found". Any idea if you were able to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

m2eclipse is the plugin you are looking for. Installation [instructions are here for eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/installing-m2eclipse.html).

Comment: hi thanxx for the reply,I tried with this (http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e) but when I press the update it shows "This repository is currently not available".But I can access it directly,don't know what to do

Comment: May be you are behind proxy or something. I installed it just yesterday

Comment: you need to post the exact error with screenshot otherwise its impossible to help. r u behind proxy? if so you need to configure the eclipse proxy settings.

Comment: I'm trying to configure with my own pc,This is the way I have done so far

Comment: I'm trying to configure with my own pc,This is the way I have done so far,Help--->Software updates--->Add site(paste the site url),After adding this tried to update,then It shows an error telling "This repository is currently not available." I have added vaadin plug-in in same way yesterday,

Comment: May the repository is down. I would try again tomorrow and if the error still exists I suggest you contact them through url: http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/getting-involved.html. By the way vaadin is a great framework

Comment: I can access repository directly,But as I think It eclips dose not recognize the url,yesterday I tried to install this got same result,Is there any way to add maven plugin ??

Comment: Ok may be the new plugin doesn't support ganymede. Why cant you switch to Galileo or Helios?

Comment: hmm sounds like good,but still I believe there should be a way to configure maven with ganymede,thanks for the support

Comment: FYI: the link now redirects to some kind of login page.

Answer (score 1):

use http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/archives/0.10.2.20100623-1649/

instead of:

http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e

Comment: I am looking for version 0.9 for linux. Any idea where will that be?